# Simulating step function in PSpice

Tags: simulation, pspice

How do I implement the the function in Pspice?

\$V_s(t)=1.5u(t)-3u(t-.01)+1.5u(t-.02)\$

I know to use the VPULSE source but it has only two voltages as parameters but I need 3.

Comment: ---> stack them

Comment: I noticed you posted a previous question about a differencing op-amp circuit and I was wondering why you'd not "accepted" one of the answers. If you did get a decent answer you can "accept" it and you might get more responses to this question. Just my personal opinion. Anyway, to be a little more helpful, if you want 3V and you have 2 x 1.5V batteries, what should you do?

Answer (score 3):

Here I inverted the middle Vsource to get the negative voltage.  You can do it with just changing the internal parameters.

[image]